# How do I cover a lengthy time period with only a few interesting details?

Tags: style, time-depiction, memoir

I'm writing a book about my three weeks of travel in Belize (is that even enough time for a book?), and I'm wondering how I can cover the first day and build a foundation without being boring. There were only a few interesting details at best on the flight between the here and Belize City, but I would like to include it to set a stage for the story.

How can I cover this time period skipping from place to place coherently and interestingly?

This is my first time trying to do any writing for my own benefit (not academics), all help appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem: Scenes that are unavoidable, but boring](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9385/problem-scenes-that-are-unavoidable-but-boring)

Comment: @what I could call that question closely related. Since that question deals with fiction, solutions would be somewhat different. (While a single question could probably cover both, I think separate questions with cross references would be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to writing, you should not try to portray things as you have seen them so, because it would not make the readers interested in it if the things you describe are not special or unusual ones. Whether you go to the places that are special or not, The writing can make them special. Or you should show the readers how did you see, feel about that, and simultaneously why did you experience it in that way.

For example: "when I was in the plane with merry mood awaiting for a spectacular touring experience. It happens in people's life when they are floating with boastful emotions, something will strike them with depressing and anxious memories of past. So as that it happened for me when I look at an air hostess who resembled like first love. It remembered me of how I was desperate for her. Still could not let, the feelings for her, go. In order to distract myself from emotional eruptions due to the memories of past, i look through the window and I was awestruck by the bird view about Belize."

Just for namesake, I created a scene it can be vividly described in more elaborate manner. You describe a place in different perspective with metaphors or with interconnections with your past experience.

Answer (score 4):

You might intersperse your travel with the basic history and geography of Belize (the interesting parts).  Pretend you (in your story) are reading a book about Belize, and skipping to the juicy bits.

Comment: That was definitely one thought I had to add detail and background, and also to lengthen the book

Answer (score 2):

Start the story with where it is interesting. It's not necessary to know that you checked your luggage, showed your passport, and got a seat on the plane. All readers know that stuff happened. So tell if it the telling adds to the story, and skip if it doesn't.

My guess is that the decision to go to Belize is probably interesting, so you might want to start with that, and then jump right to being in Belize. Or skip that, and start with this:

> After six years of dreaming, and a frantic four months of compulsive
>   planning and preparation, I was finally in Belize.